# Listing past paypal transactions with API request

Tags: paypal, transactions, rest

The goal is to list all the past transactions of a paypal account. The information that should be filtered out is: **date of the transaction, amount, payer, receiver, purpose**.
I experimented with paypal's "**transaction search api**" but the responses include a lot of unnecessary information. Furthermore, it only returns **account_id**s, e.g. "X005GHT889F". Is there a way to match the account_id with an email address or the account owner's name?

As this is a very general question, any help or hint into the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction search API can return payer_info with the email; see [its documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/transaction-search/v1/).

Alternatively, you can trigger an Activity Download in CSV format via https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome

Comment: Hi @Preston PHX, thank you for your quick response! I overlooked the part with the payer_info. So, that is helpful.

Comment: However, am I wrong to say that the Paypal API is a huge mess? E.g., why are there two objects "transaction_info" for one transaction, and why does "payer_info" contain information of the one who receives money? It's not intuitive at all.